# Merge a Partition with Unallocated Space

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, gparted

I have the following partitions on my OS:

[image]

The `dev/sde1` is the Boot Partition. The `/dev/sde5` is the `home` partition.
In between I have ~260 GB I want to merge into `home` without losing any data.

How can I do that?

Comment: You need good backups with any system change. You can use gparted from live installer. While moving partitions can be done without data loss, any file interruption will totally corrupt your data. You have to move extended partitions start left. Then move sde5 left and expand right. Do not queue steps to make sure each completes before starting another step.

Comment: I tried the Lice CD. I couldn't move it to the left.

Comment: Are all partitions including swap unmounted (little key icons)? Live installer often mounts swap and you have to swap off or unmount the swap partition to be able to edit extended partition.

Comment: I don't have SWAP partition.

Comment: You can also make a new partition in the unallocated space, clone sde5 to this and change the UUID of sde5. If all goes well delete the extended partition and resize the new partition to use the space.

Comment: Since you are only using two partitions, Vijay's suggestion is a good alternative. Longer term you may want to consider using gpt partitioning where you do not have the 4 partition limit and the issue of the extended and logical partitions. With gpt all partitions are primary and limit is 128 partitions (which even can be increased).

Comment: @oldfred, Is there a way to convert this to GPT?

Comment: You can convert, but have to add a tiny 1 or 2MB unformatted partition and then totally reinstall grub. Converting to or from GPT
http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html  Good backups are required, whether you convert or not as any partition change has some risk.

Answer (score 1):

First, backup, Backup, BACKUP!

Second, boot from a LiveCD/LiveUSB so that no `/dev/sde*` partitions are mounted.

Then, since `/dev/sde5` is part of the Extended Partition `/dev/sde2`, you'll have to add the space to `/dev/sde2`, Then merge the space with `/dev/sde5`.

Comment: How can I add space to `dev/sde2`?

Comment: right click /dev/sde2 then select Resize. as far as I remember, this is how it was done

Comment: On Lice CD there is no resize option for `dev/sde2`. Only for `dev/sde5` which of course can only be shrinked.

Comment: IIRC you have to move `sde2` to left first, then expand it to the right, and then expand `sde5`.

Comment: @danzel, The question is how to move it. See my comments above.

Comment: @Royi are any of the partitions encrypted? Are you sure none of the partitions are mounted?

Comment: How can I check for encryption? I don't think they are mounted when I do it from Live CD.

Comment: [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QSpGaeHlkoE) may help.